# Python scraping dynamic table

Tags: python, screen-scraping

I tried with several different attempts to scrape the following page:
https://www.finanzen.ch/rohstoffe/historisch/weizenpreis/euro/17.4.2022_17.5.2022

Somehow, I'm not successful with request or selenium approach.

Those anybody has an idea how to scrape the data of the historical data table?

Thanks for your hints.

ThinkerBell

Comment: Please provide some code/info of what have you done so far

Comment: Approche with Request:
import requests
url = "https://www.finanzen.ch/rohstoffe/historisch/oelpreis/usd/1.12.2021_5.4.2022"
html = requests.get(url).text
row_first_price = html.split('<div id="histroric-price-list') [0]
print(row_first_price)

Comment: Approch with Selenium:
from selenium import webdriver
URL = 'https://www.finanzen.ch/rohstoffe/historisch/weizenpreis/euro/17.4.2022_17.5.2022'
driver = webdriver.Chrome('./chromedriver')
driver.get(URL)
element = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//form[1]')
element_html=element.get_attribute('innerHTML')
import pandas
dataframes=pandas.read_html(element_html)

Comment: Okay, but edit your original question and provide the code there

Answer (score 0):

You can't bypass this website using simple requests.get, selenium/splash and even rotating-proxies won't work always. This is because, this website uses "Captcha services" and it knows how you are trying to access the page. The headers contains "Content-Disposition: form-data; name='recaptcha-token';" with a long cipher/encoded term, and since this term is based on your browsing activities, copy-pasting it in headers won't work either.

For such tricky websites, best option is to use browser based add-ons like "**iMacro**". You may also increase chances through Selenium, if you start browsing homepage and loading few more dummy links, before reaching the targeted link.